# An injectable class needs to read http headers prior to being injected into other class constructors

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to read http header keys and provide them in a service class to be used by injection to other services.

**In startup.cs** - I know this happens before the request is materialized, therefore HttpContext is null.

```
services.AddScoped<IMyConfigurationService>(provider =>
{
    string theKey = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["TheKey"].ToString();
    return new MyConfigurationService(theKey);
});
```

**In ClassA**

```
public MyCommandDirector(
    IMyConfigurationService myConfiguration)
    //IHttpContextAccessor httpContext) //<-- Can not do this. This library is shared in legacy apps.
{
   ...
}
```

The library is shared across different technologies and IHttpContextAccessor is not available in legacy win forms app. Is there another way I can inject a configuration class that has already read keys in the http header prior to injection in web api 2.0 .net core?

Comment: I think it should work if you simply get IHttpContextAccessor from service collection in your service factory. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54127696/2085502

Comment: right on! That worked. GetRequiredService() did the trick. You can add an answer if you prefer and I will add theb green check mark. Thanks!