# How to switch repositories from View ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have database and xml repositories. How I can from view switch repositories for application? For example, the view has a select:

```
<select>
    <option value="xml">XML Storage</option>
    <option value="sqldb">SQL Database</option>
</select>
```

Program.cs

```
// builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITaskRepository, TaskRepositoryXML>();
// builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepositoryXML>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITaskRepository, TaskRepositoryDB>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepositoryDB>();
```

You may have some ideas? Thank you!

Comment: If you mean at the run time a comenting out code and using instead of another class; you can not do it. You need to rebuild your project if you comment out some code and want to run them. But you can add both repositores and switch them at places you call them.

Comment: @nzrytmn, sorry, maybe confused, so I edited the code. I mean that if the selected SQL should work in the application at Dependencies Injection TaskRepositoryDB, if XML then TaskRepositoryXML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should register your services to use them in runtime, even though you want to have an option to select later on the fly.

A straightforward yet lovely approach is to use a simple `Factory` pattern. I added implementation for your `TaskRepository`, but you should do the exact implementation for the `CategoryRepository`:

```
public interface ITaskRepository
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetTasks();
}

public class XmlTaskRepository : ITaskRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetTasks() =>
        new[] { "Task1 from xml", "Task2 from xml" };
}

public class SqlTaskRepository : ITaskRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetTasks() =>
        new[] { "Task1 from sql", "Task2 from sql" };
}
```

Now you need a Factory which I implemented a simple version of it for your convenience:

```
public class TaskRepositoryFactory
{
    public ITaskRepository GetTaskRepository(string userSelection) =>
        userSelection.ToLowerInvariant() switch
        {
            "xml" => new XmlTaskRepository(),
            "sql" => new SqlTaskRepository(),
            _ => throw new ArgumentException(nameof(userSelection))
        };
}
```

Finally, you have to register your `Factory`, which I suggest using `Scope` instead of `Singletone` (Assuming that your persistence layer is based on EF Core)

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<TaskRepositoryFactory>();
```

This is all you need to do for DI. However, for illustration purposes, I added a simple page and injected the factory's concrete class, and switched to the preferred service based on `QueryString` (Its absurd, but I think enough for presenting the usage)

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly TaskRepositoryFactory _factory;

    public IndexModel(TaskRepositoryFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public List<string> TasksData { get; set; } = new();

    public void OnGet([FromQuery] string selection = "")
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selection))
        {
            var repo = _factory.GetTaskRepository(selection);
            TasksData = repo.GetTasks().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

And razor page has a simple iteration as per below:

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@foreach (var dt in Model.TasksData)
{
    <span>@dt</span><br />
}
```

We can resolve all dependencies, yet we can decide which TaskRepository would be instantiated via the help of Factory Pattern.

Comment: hello! Thank you! Intresting solution. I will definitely use it in the project. But there is another nuance. For example, I chose the SQL, you came to you, too, works immediately on SQL. Then you chose XML, I reloaded the page and I also immediately work through XML. How can I create this "Global" variable?

Comment: Your welcome. What do you mean by the "Global" variable?

Comment: Store in memory information about what type of storage is currently selected. For example, I switched to SQL, and when a new user enters the site, he will also start SQL storage. That is, the selected storage should work immediately in the entire application and in all users. If you choose XML, then the application again has to work with XML. That is to make this switch global for the whole application

Comment: You can store data in the config file or database if you prefer. However, using config file is much better I believe. for example, add `"DbToConnect": "xml"` to the appsettings.json file and read the settings and use it.

Comment: Thank you! One more question. Whether there is a way to do the formation of the desired `TaskRepository` and get it as: `ITaskRepository taskRepository` through Injection Dependency. That classes where we need to receive `TaskRepository` did not know that there is a class `TaskRepositoryFactory`. That is to hide logic `TaskRepositoryFactory`

Comment: there is a lot of information available on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127414/using-factory-pattern-with-asp-net-core-dependency-injection also remember to search "Factory Pattern with ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection"